# How to return an image from a function using BytesIO?

Tags: python, bytesio

I am trying to return a pyplot, saved as an image to a BytesIO object from a function, but can't seem to read the corresponding file.

```
def plot_Data():
    plot = plot some figure

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=100)
    buf.seek(0)

    return buf

imgData = io.BytesIO()
imgData = plot_Data()
im = xl.drawing.image.Image(imgData)
```

When I attempt the above, I get the following error:

```
--> 169         im = xl.drawing.image.Image(imgData)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py in __init__(self, img)
     30         self.ref = img
     31         mark_to_close = isinstance(img, str)
---> 32         image = _import_image(img)
     33         self.width, self.height = image.size
     34 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py in _import_image(img)
     14 
     15     if not isinstance(img, PILImage.Image):
---> 16         img = PILImage.open(img)
     17 
     18     return img

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2770         fp.seek(0)
   2771     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2772         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2773         exclusive_fp = True
   2774 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How can I return the BytesIO object from the function and read it correctly outside the function?

Comment: error shows problem in last line - `xl.drawing.image.Image(imgData)` - and probably it gets `None` instead of file - so first check `print(imgData)`. BTW if you get `BytesIO()` from `imgData = plot_Data()` then there is no need create `imgData = io.BytesIO()`

Comment: your code works for me and `print(imgData)` gives something like `<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff4d31e3530>`. Maybe you forgot `return buf` and `plot_Data` automatically returns `None` or you maybe you have other function `plot_Data` which replaces this function.
`